# R: How do I add the 95%CI derived from a percentile bootstrap of a correlation to ggplot scatterplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, correlation, scatter-plot

I can easily plot a regression line + confidence interval in a `ggplot2` `scatterplot` for correlation data using `geom_smooth`. But what I don't know how to do it use the results of a bootstrap to visualize the bootstrap confidence interval.

Consider the following:

```
library(bootES) # Library for easy bootstrapping

set.seed(5); x <- sample(50)
set.seed(6); y <- sample(50)

    biv.dat <- data.frame(x,y) # Example dataset
```

Perform bootstrap of biv.dat and computes the 95% CI using percentile method:

```
bootES(data = biv.dat, ci.conf = 0.95, ci.type = "perc") 

95.00% perc Confidence Interval, 2000 replicates
Stat        CI (Low)    CI (High)   bias        SE          
0.040       -0.243      0.336       0.008       0.149
```

Plot the scatterplot using ggplot2:

```
    plot <- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = biv.dat[,1], y = biv.dat[,2]))
```

How can I visualize the confidence interval using `CI (low) = -0.243` and `CI (high) = 0.336` in my plot?

Comment: this is a little tricky; `bootES` returns a correlation, so we would have to convert these to regression slopes and plot these as lines passing through the centroid (mean[x], mean[y]) of the data set ...

Comment: Using the boot function I can bootstrap the slope and correlation coefficient together and take the 95%CI limits. Is this the correct approach? And then plotting two lines with each of these slopes passing through the centroid?